# What does address of a, which is an array, returns?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I thought when you try to get the address of an array, it returns the address of the first element it holds.

```
int *j;
int a[5]={1,5,4,7,8};
```

Now `j=&a[0];` works perfectly fine.

Even `j=a` also does the same function.

But when I do `j=&a` it throws an error saying `cannot convert`int (*)[5]' to `int*' in assignment`

Why does it happen? &a should be the first element of the array a, so it should give &a[0].
But instead it throws an error. Can somebody explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `a` and `&a` is not the same even though they contain the same value, i.e., base address of the array `a`.

```
j = a;
```

The array name `a` here gets converted to a pointer to its first element.

Try to see what values you get via these statements to understand where the difference lies:

```
printf("%p", a+1);
printf("%p", &a+1);
```

Comment: but &a and &a[0] are of the same type, aren't they?

Comment: Basically, the type of &a[0] is int*, but the type of &a is int(*)[5]. It is like a pointer to one single huge object of five int's. Hence impossible conversion.

Comment: So is there any way i could extract the value of first address of num without using &num[0] or num?

Comment: @user3387006 - No - the base address is stored in the array name and that is your best bet.

Comment: @al-Khwārizmī: I typed your code. I guess on incrementing &a, it points to the immediate next memory location after the entire array. Nice example. Thanks.

Comment: @user3387006 - yes it demonstrates quietly nicely how the types are different. :)

Comment: The type of the thing being pointed to is an important part of a pointer. If you think of a pointer as a number then you're missing half of the story.  `&a[0]` and `&a` point at differently-sized objects, even though on most implementations they would be represented by the same number.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard says the following regarding how arrays are used in expressions (taken from C99 6.3.2.1/3 "Lvalues, array, and function designators):

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object

This is commonly known as "arrays decay to pointers".

So the sub-expression `a` in the following larger expressions evaluates to a pointer to int:

- `j=&a[0]`
- `j=a`

In the simpler expression, `j=a`, that pointer is simply assigned to `j`.

In the more complex expression, `j=&a[0]`, the 'index' operator `[]` is applied to the pointer (which is an operation equivalent to `*(a + 0)`) and the 'address-of' operator is applied to that, resulting in another pointer to int that gets assigned to `j`.

In the expression `j=&a`, the address-of operator is applied directly to the array name, and we hit one of the exceptions in the above quoted clause: "Except when it is the operand of ... the unary & operator".

Now when we look at what the standard says about the unary & (address-of) operator (C99 6.5.3.2/3 "Address and indirection operators"):

> The unary & operator returns the address of its operand. If the
>   operand has type "type", the result has type "pointer to type".

Since `a` has type "array of 5 int" (`int [5]`), the result of applying `&` to it directly has type "pointer to array of 5 int" (`int (*)[5]`), which is not assignable to `int*`.

Comment: Nice explanation. I want to point out an interesting case when arrays are used in function parameter list. Actually, a function cannot have an `array of type` parameter so it gets converted to `pointer to type` parameter. `int func(int a[]);` is exactly the same as `int func(int *a);` What happens internally for the former function declaration?

Answer (score 0):

c is a strongly typed language. Assignment such as `j=a;` is allowed only if `j` and `a` are of the same type or the compiler can safely convert `a` to `j`. In your case, type of `j` is `int *` while the type of `&a` is `int (*)[5]`. The compiler does not know how to automatically convert an object of type `int (*)[5]` to an object of type `int *`. The compiler is telling you exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an array of 5 `int`s. The pointer to `a` is a pointer to an array of five integers, or `int (*)[5]`. This is not compatible with an `int *` because of pointer arithmetic: If you increment a variable of type `int *`, the address in the variable increases by 4 (assuming 4 byte integers), so that it points to the next integer. If you increment a variable that points to an array of 5 integers, the address in the variable increases by 20 (again assuming 4 byte integers), so that it points to the next array of five integers.

Perhaps what's confusing is that the value give by `a` and `&a` is the same, as you said. The value is the same but the type is different, and the difference is most obvious when you do arithmetic on the pointers.

I hope that helps.